# Python: Pseudo-random color from a string

Tags: python, list, hash, colors, random-seed

I am doing some data visualization with Python in Blender and I need to assign colors to the data being represented. There is too much data to spend time hand-picking colors for each, so I want to generate the colors pseudo-randomly - I would like a given string to always result in the same color. That way, if it appears more than once, it will be clear that it is the same item.

For *example*, given a list like `['Moose', 'Frog', 'Your Mother']`, let's say Moose would always be maroon.

The colors are specified in RGB, where each channel is a float from `0.0` to `1.0`.

Here's what I've tried so far that isn't working:

```
import random
import hashlib

def norm(x, min, max): # this normalization function has a problem
    normalized = ( x - min(x) ) / (max(x) - min(x) )
    return normalized

def r(string, val):
    h = hash(string)
    print(h)
    if h < 0:
        h = h * -1
    rs = random.seed( int(h) + int(val) )
    output = norm(rs, 0.0, 1.0)
    return output
    
my_list = ['Moose', 'Frog', 'Your Mother']
item = my_list[0]

color = [ r(item,1), r(item,2), (item,1) ]
print(color)
```

It results in `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable` but I don't know why. I'm trying to normalize the way [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70807) demonstrates.

It might be best to have a list of possible colors, as it allows for control over the palette. Either way, I need a pseudo-random float in the range of 0.0 ~ 0.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this function. It returns a rgb value for the name by using the 3 first letters.

```
def name_color(name):
    color = [(ord(c.lower())-97)*8 for c in name[:3]] 
    return color
```

Comment: That is interesting, and I like the succinctness of it. But I want to account for all characters in the string, so that similar but not identical items will stand out from one another.

Comment: You could possible split every word in 3 parts, so the red color will be the value of the first part of the word, green will be the value of the second part etc. I think this will make a unique color for every word if im not wrong.

Comment: I also like this, but it should account for string categories which might have less than 3 characters (i.e. 2-letter iso country codes or maybe just single alphabet letters)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I didn't need to normalize or do anything fancy. `random()` returns a range between 0.0 ~ 1.0 as it is. I just needed to take a closer look at how `random.seed()` is supposed to be used.

Here's my solution:

```
import random
import hashlib

def r(string, int): # pseudo-randomization function
    h = hash( string + str(int) ) # hash string and int together
    if h < 0: # ensure positive number
        h = h * -1
    random.seed(h) # set the seed to use for randomization
    output = random.random() # produce random value in range 0.0 ~ 1.0
    output = round(output, 6) # round to 6 decimal places (optional)
    return output

my_list = ['Toyota', 'Tesla', 'Mercedes-Benz']
item = my_list[0] # choose which list item

color = [ r(item,0), r(item,1), r(item,2) ] # R,G,B values
print(item, color)
```

Output: `Toyota [0.049121, 0.383824, 0.635146]`

I may try the list approach later.